# Is it right to say "Draw it big", and if so, does that mean that "big" is an adverb?

Tags: grammaticality, predicative-complements, causative-verbs

If I have already talked about drawing a circle and want to say to draw a big circle, is it right to say it like this:

> Draw it big.

For this next sentence, would I need an adverb in the blank or an adjective?

> Draw <sub><sup>***(SOMETHING)***</sup></sub> ________ .

If an adverb *is* needed there, can I use the word *big* as that adverb? Can *big* be an adverb?

Comment: It's ***not*** an adverb. It's an adjective that describes the thing you're drawing. If you were drawing a frightening monster, you would say *"Draw it fierce"* and not *"Draw it fiercely."* If you said *"Draw it fiercely,"* then *"fierce"* would describe you while you were drawing it.

Comment: Think of the difference between 'mark an answer wrong' and 'mark an answer wrongly'.

Comment: Grammatically, *Draw a circle big* is "valid", but in practice any native speaker would normally say *Draw a big circle*.

Comment: @PeterShor - However, "big" is potentially different from "fierce", as it may be taken to apply to the verb "draw" vs the artwork produced.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - But one would not say "Draw a big it".   "Draw it big" is proper when the subject is a pronoun.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want an adverb - adverbs modify verbs.  You want an adjective, which modifies nouns.

You aren't telling somebody to change *how* they are drawing, you are asking them to change *what* they are drawing.

> Draw a bigger circle.
>
> Draw a big circle.

or with the pronoun

> Draw it big.
>
> Draw it bigger.

'big' and 'bigger' are adjectives, modifying 'circle' or 'it'.

> Draw a circle quickly.
>
> Draw it quickly.

'quickly' is an adverb, modifying 'draw'.

Comment: I completely got it. That's the best answer. Thanks.

Comment: Let me again link to [Do predicative adjuncts modify nouns or verbs](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/8438/do-predicative-adjuncts-modify-nouns-or-verbs/8439#8439)  *Big* is syntactically dependent on the verb. The word 'modify' is probably not the best one to use.